# CMake: How to execute a command before make install?

Tags: linux, cmake, installation

This is the way I install the config files:

```
file(GLOB ConfigFiles  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/configs/*.xml
                            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/configs/*.xsd
                            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/configs/*.conf)

install(FILES ${ConfigFiles} DESTINATION ${INSTDIR})
```

But I need to convert one of the xml files before installing it. There is an executable that can do this job for me:

> ./Convertor a.xml a-converted.xml

How can I automatically convert the xml file before installing it? It should be a custom command or target that installing depends on it, I just don't know how to make the `install` command depend on it though. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the [`SCRIPT` version of `install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#custom-installation-logic):

> The SCRIPT and CODE signature:
>
> `install([[SCRIPT <file>] [CODE <code>]] [...])`
>
> The SCRIPT form will invoke the given CMake script files during
> installation. If the script file name is a relative path it will be
> interpreted with respect to the current source directory. The CODE
> form will invoke the given CMake code during installation. Code is
> specified as a single argument inside a double-quoted string.

For example:

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND \"./Convertor a.xml a-converted.xml\")")
install(FILES a-converted.xml DESTINATION ${INSTDIR})
```

Be sure to checkout the [`entry for execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) in the manual. Also be aware that macro expansion inside the `CODE` parameter can be a bit tricky to get right. Check the generated `cmake_install.cmake` in your build directory where the generated code will be placed.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to executing "cd" to change directory before executing "Convertor"?

Comment: @Meysam You can specify a `WORKING_DIRECTORY` to `execute_process`.

Comment: That seems wrong. Isn't the `install(CODE ...)` expected to install the resulting file already? Also, the second `install()` could end up being executed before (or at least in parallel) if you do not have a proper dependency...

Comment: @AlexisWilke Nope, install commands [are always executed in order](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#introduction). Unlike the build phase, there is no parallelization during install. This is why CMake also does not provide mechanisms for specifying dependencies between different install steps.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your specific case would work better if you were to use a custom command and target like so:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/a-converted.xml
    COMMAND ./Convertor a.xml a-converted.xml
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Convertor
)

add_custom_target(run ALL
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/a-converted.xml
    COMMENT "Generating a-converted.xml" VERBATIM
)

install(
    FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/a-converted.xml
    DESTINATION ${INSTDIR}
)
```

*Note: I don't have all the details, so the directories are probably
not exactly what you'd want in your environment, although it's
a good idea to generate files in the `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` area.*

That way you can be sure that the file `a-converted.xml` is built at the time you want to install it. Especially, these two rules make sure that if you make changes to the original file (a.xml), it gets *recompiled*.